# Tic Tac Toe algorithm, does block move lead to draw

Tags: algorithm

Im implementing a tic tac toe algorithm where I receive a partially filled board and return the best possible move for player 1. The algorithm assumes that player 2 always makes a perfect move. Would it be enough for my algorithm to aim for a draw by simply blocking player 2, since the game will end in a draw if both players play perfectly anyways?

Comment: (Since it's the best minmax result, you cannot possibly aim higher) Reverse your statement and *aim to not lose*.

Comment: What is your algorithm?  Seems like you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: Unless you're thinking that the computer should block because then it wouldn't have to "think" as much moving forward.  In which case I ask, why does it matter?  Even running through every possible move should be quick.

Comment: On the partially filled board with rows `[...][x.o][x.o]`, X's best move is not to block O. His best move is to win the game by taking the top left corner.

Comment: To expand on my thinking,if player 1 always makes any move that blocks player 2 from winning it should result in a draw? Assuming he does not have a winning move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just do any blocking move without any other restrictions the following play is possible where the second player wins:

```
*X*    *X*    *X*    *X*    XX*    XXO    XXO    XXO
*** -> *O* -> *O* -> *O* -> *O* -> *O* -> *O* -> *OO
***    ***    *X*    *XO    *XO    *XO    XXO    XXO
```

Answer (score 0):

Just played it out, found this to be incorrect. If player 2 makes the right move he will win if player 1 is only concerned with make a winning or blocking move.